# Please let me know if I am on the right track to being an NLP Expert

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow

I am a college student(rising senior) and became interested in Natural Language Processing last semester. I decided to focus on studying this area this summer and become skilled in this area. I wanted to get some advice for studying this particular subject.

Right now, I am taking Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on Coursera to get a sense of how Machine Learning works. After finishing this course, I am planning to take Standford's CS224n NLP course on Youtube and do its class activities. I am assuming AWS and Tenserflow is also important since they are included as topics of CS224n.

I want to know if my summer plan sounds reasonable. If not, could you please give me an advice of how to make a better plan. If this sounds reasonable, it would be great if you can add more or specify which part is particularly important in these areas.

Comment: Sounds good. Replace tensorflow with pytorch unless your course includes it.

Comment: Why not tensorflow? Also, would you recommend me to add anything to or remove from my plan?

Comment: Because tensorflow does not support dynamic graphs, making debugging harder. Thank me later. Doing all these things well will keep you busy so I see no need to add anything. If you do need more material, study linear algebra, statistics, optimization, approximation/randomization algorithms, in roughly that order.

Comment: Also, why do data science people also learn how to use cloud server like AWS and Azure? What are the roles of these systems in machine learning and NLP ?

Comment: They do the boring work of provisioning and let you concentrate on what really matters. Most startups run there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely doing a great job of getting your basics down. I *really* like Patrick Winston's [AI Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjZBTDzGeGg), he does a great job of conceptualizing the math behind these problems, which is the only place I think Ng lacks.

Find a ton of papers you think are interesting, and read them top to bottom. Here is one from spotify on [NLP](http://benanne.github.io/2014/08/05/spotify-cnns.html)(super awesome)

Most importantly, IMO, the thing you need to start doing is applying the stuff you learn, to problems you think are interesting. Do a few run throughs of other stuff on github and then start doing your own!

Good luck, hope that was helpful:)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. People tell me to read a lot of research papers. But I don't think I will understand most of them at this point. Is it recommended to read them after I finish the basic studying of ML and NLP?

Comment: I do think you definitely should understand and be able to apply academic language, before jumping into academia. With that said, the paper I listed is not written overly verbosely, and you should have no issues dissecting it.

More importantly, getting your feet wet with projects in the space you want to learn is key to getting an understanding of what is happening. Although, it is very important not to just go through the motions, and actually dig into the material.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of general NLP resources:

- [How To Do Things With Words](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb) by [Peter Norvig](http://norvig.com/ipython/)
- [NLP sections](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs271/lessons/48641663/concepts/487136530923) of [Intro to Artificial Intelligence](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs271) from Udacity
- [Neural Network Methods in Natural Language Processing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1627052984) by Yoav Goldberg & Graeme Hirst

Comment: Thanks for the reply. People tell me to read a lot of research papers. But I don't think I will understand most of them at this point. Is it recommended to read them after I finish the basic studying of ML and NLP?

Comment: Research papers are mostly specific, incremental knowledge. You want a general overview of the field that is what courses and textbooks are for. You need to see the entire forest then you'll know which trees are interesting.